# Unable to suspend with FGLRX enabled

Tags: 10.10, ati, suspend, fglrx

I am unable to suspend in a fully updated (as of yesterday, 29 March 2011) Ubuntu 10.10 installation (kernel 2.6.35-28).  Following is a list of some of my hardware:

Motherboard: Gigabyte [GA-X58A-UD3R](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3449)

Video: Radeon [HD-567X-YNF3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150504)

Initially, when I went to either Suspend or Hibernate the machine would almost go into suspend, but it would never power down.  Instead it would bounce back to the login screen.  This was due to a problem with the USB3 ports being unable to suspend (noticed this in `/var/log/kern.log`).  Disabling the USB3 ports in the BIOS fixed this issue.

Now Suspend and Hibernate power down the machine.  It successfully awakens from Hibernate.  However, it will not return from suspend.  The mouse and keyboard are not powered and the monitor has no signal.  These devices are still not powered after a restart.  I must power-cycle the machine.  The `pm-suspend` log ends after it states that it entered suspend (i.e. there is no information any resume code running).

I discovered that `acpitool -s` suspends the machine and resumes successfully exactly once.  The second time the machine will not resume.  I am not sure how these two tools handle suspend differently.

UPDATE: the problem was introduced somewhere between 2.6.35-22 and 2.6.35-28.  I have both kernels install presently.  Suspend works fine with 2.6.35-22 but not with 2.6.38-28.

Answer (score 1):

Especially Suspend-and-Resume work better with a later kernel.
Installing a newer kernel is easy and even if it doesn't work, you can choose your old kernel in the grub menu when booting.

To install a kernel, please have a look at the [wiki-page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

I'd recommend 3.1.2 from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.1.2-oneiric/) because it's the latest stable version.

You need to download 3 files, the linux-headers-generic, linux-headers-all and linux-image file.

Install the 3 files with

sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb

If your computer complains about a missing module-init-tools package, you can download that [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/module-init-tools/3.12-1ubuntu6).

Install it with `sudo dpkg -i module-init-tools*.deb`and repeat the install of the 3 kernel files.

After the installation is complete, simply reboot and you will boot with your new kernel.
To make sure you are running your new kernel, open a terminal and type

```
uname -r
```

the output should be your new kernel.